# Where is the "Computer Name" screensaver stored in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, system-settings, screensaver

I've looked in:

- System/Library/Screen Savers
- Library/Screen Savers
- ~/Library/Screen Savers

I wish to explore the package contents for a personal project I'm working on. I've done iOS apps in the past, but recently got the urge to make my own screensaver.

Comment: @Kyle Why do you want to know? If you gave us more information on what you want to do, we might be able to be more helpful.

Comment: @CajunLuke sorry, long time reader first time poster on SO. I'll update my description, but I would like to explore the package contents of that particular screen saver for a personal project.

Comment: @patrix SE is not about asking why questions are asked but about answering them.

Comment: @MaxRied Sometimes if you know what they're trying to do, we can help with a better solution or say before something doesn't work. For instance, if the OP's Lion computer had lost that screensaver and they wanted to know where it was located to get it from an old Panther machine, we'd say where it was located, but that the Panther version probably won't work on Lion and provide some other ideas to fix the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Computer Name" screensaver is stored in `/System/Library/Screen\ Savers/FloatingMessage.saver`.

Displaying the computer name is just the default text for this screen saver, you can enter other texts in the Screen Saver Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

If you download and install Xcode, a very handy app called Quartz Composer is included which has a built-in mode for creating screensavers. Perhaps somebody who has Xcode installed on their machine can give you just the app itself. I don't believe it has any Xcode dependencies at all. You can even open up Apple's own screensavers with Quartz Composer to find out what they do. It is quite a cool app!

Experience:
I modified Apple's RSS Visualizer to present my school's RSS feed a little better than what the Apple & change the default colors to match my school's colors.

Unfortunately, the feed itself is not kept as up-to-date as it should, and is missing important things such as sporting events. I had fun though, and spent many hours tinkering before I dropped the project.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not the one named "FloatingMessage.saver". The one you are looking for is found at /System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Computer Name.saver